# What does a number with a colon in a schematic represent?

Tags: schematics

I am trying to understand what a numeric with a colon in the schematic below represents, like:

> I2C(1:0)

They don’t seem to be register mappings.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this schematicfrom? We need some context to answer this correctly. Usually this is used for parallel buses, but it´s really strange to show the two signals for an I2C-bus like this for example. Could just as well mean that there are two I2C-buses (I2C_0 and I2C_1).

Comment: Bus widths. I2C needs 2 signals, numbered here 0 to 1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to OrCAD/Allegro terminology, they are busses and/or netgroups. They are both signals grouped together visually into a single line on the drawing for readability.

Netgroups are just busses where member signals are given individual names instead of numerical identifiers. But at the top level it displays (n:m) just like a bus to display how many signals are present. Only when you breakout the bus into wires do you see the difference where a bus named SAMPLE_BUS(2:0) will be broken out into wires with net names:

- SAMPLE_BUS2
- SAMPLE_BUS1
- SAMPLE_BUS0

[image]

Whereas a netgroup named SAMPLE_NETGROUP(2:0) will break out into net names defined by the human.:

- SAMPLE_NETGROUP.SOME_NAME
- SAMPLE_NETGROUP.SOME_OTHER_NAME
- SAMPLE_NETGROUP.SOME_OTHER_OTHER_NAME

[image]

**WARNING:** It is possible to directly connect two bus/netgroup ports between components to each other directly with no breakout. In that case you MUST know how the software associates the signals since the port sizes and signal member names are not always identical.

For example how does BUSX(4:0) auto-connect to BUSY(8:0)? Or to BUSZ(1:5)? Does it only pair if they have the same numerical index? Or does it pair largest numerical index with smallest? And if so, does it start from the largest or smallest number and omit the rest if the sizes aren't the same?

Or how would NETGROUPX direct connect to the other three? Does it only pair signals with identical names? Or does it pair them in the order they are listed in the netgroup creation window?

- NETGROUPX.FIRST
- NETGROUPX.SECOND
- NETGROUPX.THIRD

---

- NETGROUPY.A
- NETGROUPY.B
- NETGROUPY.C

---

- NETGROUPZ.FIRST
- NETGROUPZ.SECOND
- NETGROUPZ.THIRD
- NETGROUPZ.FOURTH

---

- NETGROUPQ.A
- NETGROUPQ.B
- NETGROUPQ.THIRD
- NETGROUPQ.FOURTH

And what happens if you direct connect a bus to a netgroup?

I had to run tests with generating netlists on a test schematic and viewing it in the PCB layout ratnest to learn how it behaved. I have notes...somewhere. I *think* bus-to-bus connected by matching numberical index, netgroup-to-netgroup connected by name, but bus-to-netgroup connected by order.

---

The image below is a **bus** DirectIO being broken out to connect to two **netgroups**. Notably netgroup SWMUX. Notice that although SWMUX and KNOB2 are netgroups, they have been separated into different ports on the hierarchical block. This can be done with busses as well. Also note how one of the members of netgroup SWMUX is actually an entire bus named SW_MUX.A(0:4). 'A' stands for address as in mux address. Note how  bus SW_MUX.A and DirectIO are both broken out and manually assigned before remerging because I had no idea what the software would try and do if I connected them directly. You would also need to do this if direct connecting two buses or two netgroups if the signals did not auto-line up properly (like if everything on the port order reversed or peculiar signal arrangements in the port).

[image]

**Advice:** Only direct connect identical busses or netgroups to each other. Otherwise use breakouts even if you are just going to remerge them. For connections between identical busses but different sizes (i.e. full bus to to the same partial bus), you can name the bus line to be partial without breaking out. Otherwise you will confound readers.

Comment: So in your diagram the DirectIO buses are all connected to each other?

Comment: DirectIO[0..9] is the bus. DirectIO1, DirectIO2, etc. are each individual signals in that bus. The labels you see on every wire are net names that identify what signal it is coming from the bus. Since they are netnames, you actually do not need the wires to connect. You could disconnect the netname wire lines from the bus/netgroup lines and it would still work. As long as the bus and netgroup has been defined for that schematic, any netname following the format in that schematic will tie to that bus.

Answer (score 7):

It means that the signal is a **bus**. There are multiple individual wires/connections and they are numbered using the range of integers shown on either side of the colon.

So, I2C(1:0) is really two separate signals: I2C1 and I2C0. Some CAD tools would consider them to be I2C(1) and I2C(0) but the idea is the same.

In many cases the particular number associated with a particular signal does not matter. However, if the signals in a bus represent a binary integer then the usual convention is to treat bit 0 as the least-significant bit and the highest-numbered bit as the most-significant bit.

This is a common technique used in CAD tools to prevent schematics from becoming overly complex. Look for a component called a "bus ripper" to extract the individual signals.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about this. Two signals I2C(1) and I2C(2) makes no sense for individual signals, They should then be named I2C_CLK and I2C_DAT or similar.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny It's a bus or netgroup. They are working within the constraints of the CAD software and do not want to treat I2C_CLK and I2C_DAT as two independent signals. OrCAD has busses and newer versions added netgroups which are just busses with names for member signals, but at the top level it displays (n:m) just like a bus to display how many signals are present.